# Fails to print pointer arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So the code Im writing (for college) is supposed to do the following -
scan two pointer dynamic sized arrays and their sizes from a user and then send them to a function (arrays as pointers, sizes as integers) along with another pointer to an integer that will be used to determine the new array's size.
The function scans for numbers that are in array A but arent in array B and places such numbers in a new array, which is also dynamic and it's size is determined by the pointer ive mentioned.
The function then returns the new array's address.

Now as far as im concerned, Ive done everything right up to the point where im trying to either print the new array inside the fuction or after I return it's address.
In the first case it seems to print all sorts of crap until the program crashes, and in the second case it prints some random number (which may be an address?).

I hope I described it as clearly as possible (considering that wall of text), im not a native speaker and havent used english in regard to programming.

Help would be highly appreciated!

The code -

```
int *symmetricDiff(int *A, int sizeA, int *B, int sizeB, int *pNewSize) {
    int i, j, k = 0, cnt = 0;
    int *newArr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sizeB; j++) {
            if (A[i] == B[j]) {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        if (cnt == 0) {
            (*pNewSize)++;
            newArr = (int*)realloc(newArr, (*pNewSize + 1) * sizeof(int));
            if (newArr == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to allocate memory");
                return 0;
            }
            *(newArr+k) = *(A+i);
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("The new array's size is %d\n", *pNewSize);
    for (i = 0; i < pNewSize; i++) {
        printf("The new array is %d\n", *(newArr + i));
    }
    return &newArr;
}

int main() {
    int numcase, sizeA, sizeB, *pNewSize = 0, i, *A, *B;
    while (1) {
        printf("Pick a function to activate\n 1 - First paragraph\n 2 - Second paragraph\n 3 - Third paragraph\n 0 - Terminate the application\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &numcase);
        switch (numcase) {
        case 0:
            return 0;
            printf("\n\n");
            break;

        case 1:
            printf("Enter a size for the first array\n");
            scanf("%d", &sizeA);
            A = (int*)malloc(sizeA * sizeof(int));
            if (A == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to allocate memory");
                return;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
                printf("Enter a number for the first array\n");
                scanf("%d", &A[i]);
            }
            printf("Enter a size for the second array\n");
            scanf("%d", &sizeB);
            B = (int*)malloc(sizeB * sizeof(int));
            if (B == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to allocate memory");
                return;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < sizeB; i++) {
                printf("Enter a number for the second array\n");
                scanf("%d", &B[i]);
            }
            printf("check\n");
            symmetricDiff(A, sizeA, B, sizeB, &pNewSize);
        /*  for (i = 0; i < pNewSize; i++);
            printf("The new array is %d\n", **(symmetricDiff));*/
            printf("spcheck\n");
            printf("\n\n");
            free(A);
            free(B);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Incorrent input\n");
            printf("\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return &newArr` should be `return newArr`. Your compiler should have warned you about that. In fact it should have given you two warnings (incorrect return type and returning address of local variable). Do not ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: `return &newArr;` you return an `int**` You should activate your compilator warnings

Comment: Wow thanks alot! first post on this forum, you helped me fix it and understand my mistakes in like 10 mins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping with your original design for symmetricDiff()
the biggest problem I see you are returning the
address of your local variable 'newArr' instead of the value.

I would suggest polishing your mental model of stack vs. heap storage and
drawing a diagram of the various pointers and storage in play.
Note: this is easier to do with pencil & paper :-)

I added a fair number of print statements to your code to help show what was happening to the variables.

I also added a test hook - see option #9 (it just assigns some hardwired values to A and B, because I didn't want to do data entery each time every time I ran the program).

My goal with the print statents is to give you an idea about how you can print values and addresses in various places and see what the code is actually doing (because more often than I care to admit, the code doesn't always do what we *think* it is doing :-) ).

Browse through the actual output (below, first) and reference that against the modified source code (below, second).

Check the values of your variables (and their addresses) and see if that helps untangle your original code.

Good luck and happy coding :-)

p.s. the prints are rather verbose, my apologies for that - I wanted to keep the debugging additions as simple as possible, and without wrapping things up in a struct or something it seems like "printf" was the way to go.

The takehome messages here would be 1) remember you can add enough prints to show pretty much whatever is going on, and 2) once you wrap your head around addresses and pointers you won't need to go as crazy as I did here.

### OUTPUT (from modified code)

```
$ ./a.out

-----
Pick a function to activate
1 - First paragraph
2 - Second paragraph
3 - Third paragraph
9 - test
0 - Terminate the application
9
You entered 9...

main(): testing.  Before we initialze too much, lets see what is going on with our local vars...
Testing... just for illustration let's print out the address of our local vars:
type    varname      value      address                       sizeof
------  ------- ----------     -----------------         ----------------
int   numcase =          9   &numcase=   BC7A898     sizeof(  numcase )=4
int     sizeA =          0     &sizeA=   BC7A894     sizeof(    sizeA )=4
int*        A =     4012A0         &A=   BC7A888     sizeof(        A )=8
int     sizeB =         52     &sizeB=   BC7A884     sizeof(    sizeB )=4
int*        B =     4012E5     &sizeB=   BC7A878     sizeof(        B )=8
int  sizeDiff =      32766  &sizeDiff=   BC7A874     sizeof( sizeDiff )=4
int*     Diff =     40051B      &Diff=   BC7A868     sizeof(     Diff )=8
main(): numcase should be 9 becuase we chose the 'test' option.
      : sizeA and sizeB aren't yet initialized.
      : Also A, B, and Diff don't point to known values (they are
      : are not valid heap addresses yet because we haven't assigned them).
      : Just for fun, notice on the far right that our integers are all 4 bytes (32 bit)
      : while the pointers are all 8 bytes (64 bits).


main():Before symmetricDiff()... (skipping addresses and sizeofs for local vars, no changes there)
type    varname      value
------  ------- ----------
int   numcase =          9
int     sizeA =          4
int*        A =     A25010
int     sizeB =          3
int*        B =     A25030
int  sizeDiff =      32766
int*     Diff =     40051B
main():numcase should still be 9.
      :sizeA and sizeB should now be 4 and 3 respectively.
      :A and B should point to something on our heap - thanks, malloc().
      :sizeDiff and Diff should still be the same (e.g. uninitialized).

symmetricDiff(): Very beginning.  Before we initialze too much, lets see what is going on with our params and local vars...
type    varname      value      address                       sizes
------  ------- ----------     -----------------         ----------------
int     sizeA =          4     &sizeA=   BC7A814    sizeof(   sizeA )=4
int*        A =     A25010         &A=   BC7A818    sizeof(       A )=8
int     sizeB =          3     &sizeB=   BC7A804    sizeof(   sizeB )=4
int*        B =     A25030         &B=   BC7A808    sizeof(       B )=8
int         i =         52         &i=   BC7A83C    sizeof(       i )=4
int         j = -943289501         &j=   BC7A838    sizeof(       j )=4
int       cnt =          0       &cnt=   BC7A834    sizeof(     cnt )=4
int*   newArr =         47    &newArr=   BC7A828    sizeof(  newArr )=8
int* pNewSize =    BC7A874  &pNewSize=   BC7A7F8    sizeof(pNewSize )=8
symmetricDiff(): notice that sizeA, sizeB, A and B have the same values here but different addresses.
               : IMPORTANT - note that the values of main's A and our A (here in symmetricDiff) are the same,
               : but the ADDRESSES of main's A and symmetricDiff's A are different.
               : Also note that the VALUE of symmetricDiff's pNewSize matches the ADDRESS of main's sizeDiff.
               : Except for cnt, our local vars i, j, and newArr have more or less random values becuase they're
               : not yet initialized.

symmetricDiff(): looping, i=0
int       cnt =          0
int*   newArr =   10637392
symmetricDiff(): i will change.  j should be last value assigned (dont really care about that).
               : Also no change for sizeA, A, sizeB, B.
               : cnt may change, if so the value (heap location) of newArray may be changed because of realloc().

symmetricDiff(): looping, i=1
int       cnt =          0
int*   newArr =   10637392
symmetricDiff(): i will change.  j should be last value assigned (dont really care about that).
               : Also no change for sizeA, A, sizeB, B.
               : cnt may change, if so the value (heap location) of newArray may be changed because of realloc().

symmetricDiff(): looping, i=2
int       cnt =          1
int*   newArr =   10637392
symmetricDiff(): i will change.  j should be last value assigned (dont really care about that).
               : Also no change for sizeA, A, sizeB, B.
               : cnt may change, if so the value (heap location) of newArray may be changed because of realloc().

symmetricDiff(): looping, i=3
int       cnt =          2
int*   newArr =   10637392
symmetricDiff(): i will change.  j should be last value assigned (dont really care about that).
               : Also no change for sizeA, A, sizeB, B.
               : cnt may change, if so the value (heap location) of newArray may be changed because of realloc().

The new array's size is 2
newArr[0]=101
newArr[1]=102

symmetricDiff(): Ready to return, will return newArr's value (A25050) to caller.
type    varname      value
------  ------- ----------
int     sizeA =          4
int*        A =     A25010
int     sizeB =          3
int*        B =     A25030
int         i =          2
int         j =          3
int       cnt =          2
int*   newArr =     A25050
int* pNewSize =    BC7A874
symmetricDiff(): no changes for values of sizeA, sizeB, A and B.
               : i and j and cnt did change from beginning.
               : pNewSize *looks* like id didn't change, it still has the same value.
               : But what pNewSize *points* to did change.
               : Now *pNewSize=2 which should be the same as 'cnt'

main():After symmetricDiff()...
type    varname      value
------  ------- ----------
int   numcase =          9
int     sizeA =          4
int*        A =     A25010
int     sizeB =          3
int*        B =     A25030
int  sizeDiff =          2
int*     Diff =     A25050
main():No change for numcase, sizeA, sizeB, A, and B
      :sizeDiff and Diff reflect what symmetricDiff() did.
      :Now that Diff is pointing to the new 'array' in heap storage
      :Thank you, symmetricDiff, now we can safely print the array.
------------------
main(): The new array's size is 2
   Diff[0]=101
   Diff[1]=102

-----
Pick a function to activate
1 - First paragraph
2 - Second paragraph
3 - Third paragraph
9 - test
0 - Terminate the application
0
You entered 0...
$
```

### MODIFIED CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*
 * I added some code to print pointer values and addresses... to make alingment
 * work better I'm using %10d for all memory locations as well as normal integers.
 * In my own code I tend to use %X for memory locations, but it makes it harder to
 * keep things alinged and I felt the visual benefit of slightly easier reading
 * was worth not using hex for addresses.
 */

int *symmetricDiff(int *A, int sizeA
                 , int *B, int sizeB
                 , int *pNewSize ) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int cnt = 0;
    /* int IGNORE_k = 0; */
    /* I changed 'k' to IGNORE_k because 'cnt' is sufficient. */
    int *newArr; /* left uninitialized just to show beofre & after values. */


    printf("\nsymmetricDiff(): Very beginning.  Before we initialze too much, lets see what is going on with our params and local vars...\n");
    printf("type    varname %10s      address%10s             sizes\n",     "value",    "" );
    printf("------  ------- %10s     -------%10s         ----------------\n", "----------", "----------" );
    printf("int     sizeA = %10d     &sizeA=%10X    sizeof(   sizeA )=%d\n", sizeA,      &sizeA,     sizeof(sizeA)    );
    printf("int*        A = %10X         &A=%10X    sizeof(       A )=%d\n", A,          &A,         sizeof(A)        );
    printf("int     sizeB = %10d     &sizeB=%10X    sizeof(   sizeB )=%d\n", sizeB,      &sizeB,     sizeof(sizeB)    );
    printf("int*        B = %10X         &B=%10X    sizeof(       B )=%d\n", B,          &B,         sizeof(B)        );
    printf("int         i = %10d         &i=%10X    sizeof(       i )=%d\n", i,          &i,         sizeof(i)        );
    printf("int         j = %10d         &j=%10X    sizeof(       j )=%d\n", j,          &j,         sizeof(j)        );
    printf("int       cnt = %10d       &cnt=%10X    sizeof(     cnt )=%d\n", cnt,        &cnt,       sizeof(cnt)      );
    printf("int*   newArr = %10X    &newArr=%10X    sizeof(  newArr )=%d\n", newArr,     &newArr,    sizeof(newArr)   );
    printf("int* pNewSize = %10X  &pNewSize=%10X    sizeof(pNewSize )=%d\n", pNewSize,   &pNewSize,  sizeof(pNewSize) );
    printf("symmetricDiff(): notice that sizeA, sizeB, A and B have the same values here but different addresses.\n");
    printf("               : IMPORTANT - note that the values of main's A and our A (here in symmetricDiff) are the same,\n");
    printf("               : but the ADDRESSES of main's A and symmetricDiff's A are different.\n");
    printf("               : Also note that the VALUE of symmetricDiff's pNewSize matches the ADDRESS of main's sizeDiff.\n");
    printf("               : Except for cnt, our local vars i, j, and newArr have more or less random values becuase they're\n");
    printf("               : not yet initialized.\n");

    newArr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
        printf("\nsymmetricDiff(): looping, i=%d\n", i);
        printf("int       cnt = %10d\n", cnt    );
        printf("int*   newArr = %10d\n", newArr );
        printf("symmetricDiff(): i will change.  j should be last value assigned (dont really care about that).\n");
        printf("               : Also no change for sizeA, A, sizeB, B.\n");
        printf("               : cnt may change, if so the value (heap location) of newArray may be changed because of realloc().\n");
        for (j = 0; j < sizeB; j++) {
            if( A[i] == B[j] ) {
                newArr[cnt] = A[i];
                cnt++;
                /* Let's wait to tell our caller about what happened until just before we return.
                 * We can just use local var 'cnt' for now...
                 *   (*pNewSize)++;
                 *   newArr = (int*)realloc(newArr, (*pNewSize + 1) * sizeof(int));
                 * After all we did increment 'cnt' just above here.
                 */
                newArr = (int*)realloc(newArr, cnt * sizeof(int));
                if (newArr == NULL) {
                    printf("Failed to allocate memory");
                    /* return 0; /* using NULL instead of 0 probalby better style here. */
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* print out what we found. */
    /* We'll use 'cnt' here... caller can use whatever pNewSize points to.
     * OLD:   printf("The new array's size is %d\n", *pNewSize);
     * OLD:   for (i = 0; i < pNewSize; i++) {
     * OLD:       printf("The new array is %d\n", *(newArr + i));
     * OLD:   }
     */
    printf("\nThe new array's size is %d\n", cnt );
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        printf("newArr[%d]=%d\n", i, newArr[i] );
        /* Or if you prefer:
         *    printf("newArr[%d]=%d\n", i, *(newArr+i) );
         *  newArr[i] is just a short hand expression for *(newArr+i)
         */
    }

    /* Now that we are done with all the work let's tell our caller what we found.  */
    *pNewSize = cnt;
    /* DANGER: this way we were returning the ADDRESS of our local pointer "newArr".
     *    return &newArr;
     * The address you want to return is whatever was last allocated (malloc or realloc)
     * on the heap, which is the value of newArr.
     */
    printf("\nsymmetricDiff(): Ready to return, will return newArr's value (%X) to caller.\n", newArr);
    printf("type    varname %10s\n", "value" );
    printf("------  ------- %10s\n", "----------" );
    printf("int     sizeA = %10d\n", sizeA       );
    printf("int*        A = %10X\n", A           );
    printf("int     sizeB = %10d\n", sizeB       );
    printf("int*        B = %10X\n", B           );
    printf("int         i = %10d\n", i           );
    printf("int         j = %10d\n", j           );
    printf("int       cnt = %10d\n", cnt         );
    printf("int*   newArr = %10X\n", newArr      );
    printf("int* pNewSize = %10X\n", pNewSize    );
    printf("symmetricDiff(): no changes for values of sizeA, sizeB, A and B.\n");
    printf("               : i and j and cnt did change from beginning.\n");
    printf("               : pNewSize *looks* like id didn't change, it still has the same value.\n");
    printf("               : But what pNewSize *points* to did change.\n");
    printf("               : Now *pNewSize=%d which should be the same as 'cnt'\n", *pNewSize );
    return newArr;
    /* To elaborate, the original code was returning the ADDRESS of local variable 'newArr'
     * which is a problem because that address is going to evaporate the instant we
     * return from the function (e.g. stack storage goes away; strictly speaking it won't evaporate
     * but it will be IMMEDIATELY recycled and have a other values stored in it, and those other values
     * are almost never going to have anything to do wiht what 'newArr' was pointing to on the heap.
     */
}

int main() {
    int numcase;
    int sizeA;
    int *A;
    int sizeB;
    int *B;
    /* int *IGNORE_pNewSize = 0;  newSize should be an actual integer,  not a pointer to an integer */
    int sizeDiff; /* name change to match sizeA convention.  we wil pass the address of this int to symmetricDiff. */
    int *Diff;
    int i;
    while (1) {
        printf("\n-----\nPick a function to activate\n");
        printf("1 - First paragraph\n");
        printf("2 - Second paragraph\n");
        printf("3 - Third paragraph\n");
        printf("9 - test\n"); /* NEW: added to simplify testing. */
        printf("0 - Terminate the application\n");
        scanf("%d", &numcase);
        printf("You entered %d...\n", numcase );
        switch (numcase) {
        case 0:
            return 0;
            printf("\n\n");
            break;

        case 1:
            printf("Enter a size for the first array\n");
            scanf("%d", &sizeA);
            A = (int*)malloc(sizeA * sizeof(int));
            if (A == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to allocate memory");
                return;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
                printf("Enter a number for the first array\n");
                scanf("%d", &A[i]);
            }
            printf("Enter a size for the second array\n");
            scanf("%d", &sizeB);
            B = (int*)malloc(sizeB * sizeof(int));
            if (B == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to allocate memory");
                return;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < sizeB; i++) {
                printf("Enter a number for the second array\n");
                scanf("%d", &B[i]);
            }
            printf("check\n");
        /* fix me:    symmetricDiff(A, sizeA, B, sizeB, &pNewSize); */
        /*  for (i = 0; i < pNewSize; i++);
            printf("The new array is %d\n", **(symmetricDiff));*/
            printf("spcheck\n");
            printf("\n\n");
            free(A);
            free(B);
            break;

        case 9: /* NEW: added to simplify testing. */
           printf("\nmain(): testing.  Before we initialze too much, lets see what is going on with our local vars...\n");
           printf("Testing... just for illustration let's print out the address of our local vars:\n");
           printf("type    varname %10s      address%10s             sizeof\n",     "value",    "" );
           printf("------  ------- %10s     -------%10s         ----------------\n", "----------", "----------" );
           printf("int   numcase = %10d   &numcase=%10X     sizeof(  numcase )=%d\n", numcase,    &numcase,   sizeof(numcase)  );
           printf("int     sizeA = %10d     &sizeA=%10X     sizeof(    sizeA )=%d\n", sizeA,      &sizeA,     sizeof(sizeA)    );
           printf("int*        A = %10X         &A=%10X     sizeof(        A )=%d\n", A,          &A,         sizeof(A)        );
           printf("int     sizeB = %10d     &sizeB=%10X     sizeof(    sizeB )=%d\n", sizeB,      &sizeB,     sizeof(sizeB)    );
           printf("int*        B = %10X     &sizeB=%10X     sizeof(        B )=%d\n", B,          &B,         sizeof(B)        );
           printf("int  sizeDiff = %10d  &sizeDiff=%10X     sizeof( sizeDiff )=%d\n", sizeDiff,   &sizeDiff,  sizeof(sizeDiff) );
           printf("int*     Diff = %10X      &Diff=%10X     sizeof(     Diff )=%d\n", Diff,       &Diff,      sizeof(Diff)     );
           printf("main(): numcase should be 9 becuase we chose the 'test' option.\n");
           printf("      : sizeA and sizeB aren't yet initialized.\n");
           printf("      : Also A, B, and Diff don't point to known values (they are\n");
           printf("      : are not valid heap addresses yet because we haven't assigned them).\n");
           printf("      : Just for fun, notice on the far right that our integers are all 4 bytes (32 bit)\n");
           printf("      : while the pointers are all 8 bytes (64 bits).\n");
           printf("\n");

           sizeA = 4; A = (int*)malloc(sizeA * sizeof(int));

           sizeB = 3; B = (int*)malloc(sizeB * sizeof(int));
           if (A == NULL || B == NULL) {
               printf("Failed to allocate memory");
               return;
           }
           A[0] = 100; A[1] = 101; A[2] = 102; A[3] = 103;
           B[0] = 101; B[1] = 102; B[2] = 400;

           printf("\nmain():Before symmetricDiff()... (skipping addresses and sizeofs for local vars, no changes there)\n");
           printf("type    varname %10s\n", "value" );
           printf("------  ------- %10s\n", "----------" );
           printf("int   numcase = %10d\n", numcase  );
           printf("int     sizeA = %10d\n", sizeA    );
           printf("int*        A = %10X\n", A        );
           printf("int     sizeB = %10d\n", sizeB    );
           printf("int*        B = %10X\n", B        );
           printf("int  sizeDiff = %10d\n", sizeDiff );
           printf("int*     Diff = %10X\n", Diff     );
           printf("main():numcase should still be 9.\n");
           printf("      :sizeA and sizeB should now be 4 and 3 respectively.\n");
           printf("      :A and B should point to something on our heap - thanks, malloc().\n");
           printf("      :sizeDiff and Diff should still be the same (e.g. uninitialized).\n");

           Diff = symmetricDiff(
               A, sizeA,
               B, sizeB,
               &sizeDiff );
           printf("\nmain():After symmetricDiff()...\n");
           printf("type    varname %10s\n", "value" );
           printf("------  ------- %10s\n", "----------" );
           printf("int   numcase = %10d\n", numcase  );
           printf("int     sizeA = %10d\n", sizeA    );
           printf("int*        A = %10X\n", A        );
           printf("int     sizeB = %10d\n", sizeB    );
           printf("int*        B = %10X\n", B        );
           printf("int  sizeDiff = %10d\n", sizeDiff );
           printf("int*     Diff = %10X\n", Diff     );
           printf("main():No change for numcase, sizeA, sizeB, A, and B\n");
           printf("      :sizeDiff and Diff reflect what symmetricDiff() did.\n");
           printf("      :Now that Diff is pointing to the new 'array' in heap storage\n");
           printf("      :Thank you, symmetricDiff, now we can safely print the array.");
           printf("\n------------------\n");
           printf("main(): The new array's size is %d\n", sizeDiff);
           for (i = 0; i < sizeDiff; i++) {
               printf("   Diff[%d]=%d\n", i, Diff[i] );
           }
           break;
        default:
            printf("Incorrent input\n");
            printf("\n\n");
            break;
        }
        /* WARNING: if you're going to run this in a loop you should
         * probably free the heap storage owned by A, B, and Diff.
         * Otherwise the next time through the loop will leak memory.
         * Before doing that, go ahead and run '9' a few times and
         * see if the memory locations stay the same for A, B, and Diff.
         *    free( A );
         *    free( B );
         *    free( Diff );
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: @Akra,  you're welcome :-)  I wouldn't complain if you were to select this as an answer.  Most everything I added is "just" printfs(), you can learn a lot about your code by printing things out.  Good luck :-)

Answer (score 3):

The end of your function:

```
printf("The new array's size is %d\n", *pNewSize);
for (i = 0; i < pNewSize; i++) {
    printf("The new array is %d\n", *(newArr + i));
}
return &newArr;
```

There are two errors here. The first is that `pNewSize` is a pointer and needs to be dereferenced in the `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < *pNewSize; i++) {
```

The second, as mentioned in the comments, is that `newArr` is already a pointer, ready to be returned like so:

```
return newArr;
```

Also, in `main()`,

```
int numcase, sizeA, sizeB, *pNewSize = 0, i, *A, *B;
```

should be

```
int numcase, sizeA, sizeB, newSize = 0, i, *A, *B;
```

and passed by address in the function call:

```
symmetricDiff(A, sizeA, B, sizeB, &newSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this small bit is correct since you said you want to move the different values across, so it should be if `cnt != 0;` if I am understanding correctly.

```
if (cnt == 0) {
        (*pNewSize)++;
        newArr = (int*)realloc(newArr, (*pNewSize + 1) * sizeof(int));
        if (newArr == NULL) {
            printf("Failed to allocate memory");
            return 0;
        }
        *(newArr+k) = *(A+i);
        k++;
    }
```

But since you are confident in your code, other than printing, "Ive done everything right up to the point where im trying to either print the new array inside the function or after I return it's address".

However, as @kaylum mentioned, you are returning a pointer to a pointer `return &newArr;` where you should just do `return newArr;`. Then to print it, you will need to de-reference the return value. However, since this is actually an array, not just one value, you will need to loop over all values in the array and print them, but to do this you need to catch the return value. I.E.

```
int * returnArr = symmetricDiff(A, sizeA, B, sizeB, &pNewSize);
for(i = 0; i < *pNewSize; i++){
    printf("%d ",returnArr[i]);
}
```

The above code should be in main.

Your commented print `printf("The new array is %d\n", *(symmetricDiff));` is printing the dereferenced pointer to the function symmetricDiff.

Finally, when you declare `*pNewSize`, do not set it equal to zero. You are effectively setting the address of the variable to 0.